# Add integer value to date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, integer

In excel with Microsoft query, we have one column which is formatted as date called "JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE".

The second column(DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME) contains days, formated as numbers, example "40","10" and "5".

We want to create a filter that sorts out hits with dates over for example: CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE+"40".

Me and my collegues knowlegde about SQL is obviosly very limited, but so far we  came up with:

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.MATNR = JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.MATNR AND 
DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.PLANT = JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.PLANT AND 
 ((JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE<(NOW()+DATEADD(DAY,DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME, JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE)))
```

The error occurs on the last row, which is the one we have written ourselves (Big surprise there).

Picture in Microsoft query:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: There are some errors on your query. For example "From" (from what?) and "Where" (why two where?).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I can type in the complete statement which is a wall of text. But i skiped all the pointless stuff that works, and just typed in the part were the error occurs.

Comment: What field type is `CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE` and `TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME`? I suspect either your date isn't stored as a date, or your `TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME` isn't numeric (and may have a record with a non-numeric value in it). You can't do date logic on things that just look like dates, but aren't stored as dates. And you can't do math with things that aren't numbers. Also, please share the error you are receiving. There is a wealth of information there.

Comment: Check my edit @JNevill

Comment: Best guess here is that here: `(NOW()+DATEADD(DAY,DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME, JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE)` you are adding two dates together and it's having a problem with that. Furthermore `DateAdd` is not a `MySQL` function and that is no doubt confusing the heck out of mysql when you try to do it. If you want records where the current date is greater than the `Confirmed_Del_Date` + `Total_Rep_Leadtime` in MySQL try: `WHERE CURDATE() > DATE_ADD(JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.CONFIRMED_DEL_DATE, INTERVAL DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME DAY)`

Comment: @Sam Before I even start evaluating your SQL, I presume the error isn't because you're missing a right parenthesis at the end?

Comment: Sorry for my late response but i had to leave work... I tried out that code @Jnevill and i dont get any errors. But still dosent seem to filter away the hits with dates higher than confirmed date + total replenishment leadtime.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni I tried with several parenthesis and less just to be sure, but it isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your error is to do with how you are trying to manipulate dates. From your query, it's quite difficult to understand exactly what you want, but I believe you're looking for something similar to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB1ARTSTATDAY_0 a
JOIN JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0 AS b ON a.MATNR = b.MATNR 
                       AND a.PLANT = b.PLANT 
WHERE b.REQUESTED_DEL_DATE < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL a.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME DAY)
```

This selects values where today's date is after the confirmed delete date plus the number of days in the Total_rep_leadtime column.

A more readable example of this working here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e15d1/1)

Edit: I've made the query a bit more readable using aliases for the table names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Due to my lack of experience and knowledge i asked this question very poorly, but thanks to you I have figured out a way to make it work!

I supplied you with the wrong logic... (sorry), but when I saw how this code was written I changed it a bit and now I beleve it works:
JM5OPENORDERSDAY_0.REQUESTED_DEL_DATE < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DB1ARTSTATDAY_0.TOTAL_REP_LEADTIME DAY)

(It was REQUESTED_DEL_DATE and not Confirmed date, but it dosent matter just, just FYI)

Comment: @Sam Great. I have updated my answer to reflect this. If my answer helped, feel free to upvote it, or mark it correct.